# PHP randomly select from a list

Tags: php, random, sampling

I am currently working with PHP code that random selects colors:

```
<div onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink() ?>';" 
    style="cursor:pointer;background:#<?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php 
        echo rand(0, 9); ?>;" 
    class="post bg thickbox" 
    id="thickbox post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

What I would prefer to do is define a list of preferred colors in one PHP file, and then randomly sample an element from this list in the code above.

What is the correct PHP code for randomly sampling such a list of colors? How would you define the list of colors?

Comment: `<?php echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php echo rand(0, 9); ?><?php echo rand(0, 9);` could have just been `for(i=0; i<6; i++) echo rand(0,9);`. Anyway the other solutions proposed are definitely better

Comment: He wants a list of predefined colors and not some completely random color. Anyway, this solution is very dirty.

Comment: @0x90: I know, I was just pointing out that a `for` cycle would have already made his code 10 times clearer

Comment: @nico, you could really clean up with `printf("%06X\n", rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));`

Comment: @evilclown: which doesn't give the same result :) Really, I was not proposing a solution, just pointing out that you don't generally need to repeat the same instruction 6 times, that's all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do like most have suggested, define your colors as an array in one php file:

```
$colors = array("red", "blue", "#00ff00");
```

And then use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to select one:

```
...background:<?= $colors[array_rand($colors, 1)] ?>;" class=...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an array of colors and select one entry using rand(0, to) as the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function getRandomColor(){
    $a = array('#ff5500', '#000066', '#555555');
    $indice = rand(0, count($a)-1);
    return $a[$indice];
}
```